# how to edit the particular user details in profile page of User module in django

Tags: django

I created the signup form and login form.Now I want to edit and delete the particular details of signup form.I tried it with below code but it is not working.It is allowing me only to edit the admin panel user details only.

Here is my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserProfileInfo
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
         model = UserProfileInfo
         fields = [ ]

class editProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','email','password']
        help_texts={
            'username': None
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserForm,UserProfileInfoForm,editProfile

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



def edit_profile(request):
    if request.POST:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        user.username=request.POST.get('user')                    
        user.email=request.POST.get('email') 
        user.first_name=request.POST.get('first_name')                    
        user.last_name=request.POST.get('last_name')
        user.password=request.POST.get('password')                    

        user.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signupapp:index'))    

    user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
    return render_to_response('edit.html',{'profile':user_profile },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: You've defined a form but you are not using it in your view. You should start by reading the [documentation on how to use forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view), particularly the section on views